# ObjectAnimator.ofFloat can't take Int as parameters directly in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am working on a kotlin Project and i try to convert a method in java to kotlin.
I am now getting this error

**None of  the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied.**

it  occurs on the `ObjectAnimator.ofFloat()`

The Code is below

**Code**

```
fun animate(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, goesDown: Boolean) {

    val animat = AnimatorSet()

    val objectY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(holder.itemView, "translationY", if (goesDown) 200 else -200, 0)
    objectY.setDuration(Kons.Duration.toLong())

    val objectX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(holder.itemView, "translationX", -50, 50, -30, 30, -20, 20, -5, 5, 0)
    objectX.setDuration(Kons.Duration.toLong())

    animat.playTogether(objectX, objectY)
    animat.start()
}
```

Comment: Which function cannot be called with the arguments supplied? Please provide the full error message.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Seemingly, the error is caused by the fact that Kotlin, unlike Java, [does not promote integer literals to floating point types](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html#numbers). You have to write them as, for example, `200f`, and fix these two lines:

```
val objectY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(holder.itemView, View.TRANSLATION_Y, if (goesDown) 200f else -200f, 0f)
```

```
val objectX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(holder.itemView, View.TRANSLATION_X, -50f, 50f, -30f, 30f, -20f, 20f, -5f, 5f, 0f)
```

Comment: Yep, same here. Just call `.toFloat()` on the value or append `F`.